# How to solve failed flyway validation?

Tags: database, upgrade, flyway

After dropping all tables user schemas this is the error trying to run the flyway install:

```
ERROR: FlywayException: Validate failed. Found differences between applied migrations and available migrations: Detected applied migration missing on the classpath: 2.001
ERROR: Occured in com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.doValidate() at line 941
An ERROR has occurred migrating the SYSTEM Schema, execution aborted
```

Any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade was being done against an OracleXE database. I used

```
sqlplus
```

with `system` username and password that was configured at the installation and:

```
truncate table "schema_version";
commit;
```